# How setup my mono app from unix?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, mono

I create mono app (C#,winforms)

but I do not understand how do I install on unix platform? for example ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most .NET applications can be deployed by copying the assemblies and configuration files.

This applies to unix/linux as well.

With mono, you need to launch the application with mono:

```
mono myapp.exe
```

If you are talking about an "installer", the linux term is "package" and packaging for linux is a large and complex topic. See [this article](http://freshmeat.net/articles/lessons-in-packaging-linux-applications) for a flavor of what is involved.

Answer (score 0):

First, Ubuntu or any other Linux distros are not UNIX.

Second, check if Mono is already installed on Ubuntu. If not, install it in this way,

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Third, zip up your binaries as well as all its dependencies and copy to the Ubuntu box. Extract them there and run "mono yourapp.exe". At least that's how I now package up my WinForms things for Linux.

Don't expect it to run in most cases, as you have to troubleshoot compatibility issues,

http://mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications